# NULL Value coming in result although value exists

Tags: sql, oracle

*Changed [the query to new suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58907979/146325) and faced another issue hence posting as NEW POST*

I have created the below query to give results for those employees whose payroll action type is either not there in the table `PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS`
or the action_type is 'Q' ,'R' .

Now, the below query is returning values for one particular employee but it is returning both null and 'Q','R'. Now, if on a particular date the employee has a value 'Q' OR 'R' then how can it return null as well?

[image]

I need to add a condition in the below query such that if an employee has `ACTION_TYPE_code` 'Q','R' then it does not go to the NULL condition.

i.e. for the above employee, 636 as the query has fetched action_type not null, the NULL action_type should not be returned...

it should only be returned if the `ACTION_TYPE IS NULL` and no other value at that particular date

```
select * 
from 
(SELECT DISTINCT
    PAPF.PERSON_NUMBER,
    NAME.FIRST_NAME,
    NAME.LAST_NAME,
    PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_NUMBER,
    PY.PAYROLL_NAME,
    PPA.ACTION_TYPE ACTION_TYPE_code,
    (
        SELECT
            MEANING
        FROM
            FND_LOOKUP_VALUES
        WHERE
            LOOKUP_TYPE = 'ACTION_TYPE'
            AND LOOKUP_CODE = PPA.ACTION_TYPE
            AND LANGUAGE = 'US'
            AND ENABLED_FLAG = 'Y'
    ) ACTION_TYPE,
    TO_CHAR(PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE, 'DD-MON-YYYY') EFFECTIVE_DATE,
    PPA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID   ACTION_NUMBER,
    PCS.CONSOLIDATION_SET_NAME,
    TO_CHAR(FINC, 'DD-MON-YYYY') FINC,
    PASV.USER_STATUS
FROM
    PAY_ASSIGNED_PAYROLLS_DN PAPD
    JOIN PAY_PAYROLL_TERMS PT ON ( PAPD.PAYROLL_TERM_ID = PT.PAYROLL_TERM_ID )
    JOIN PAY_PAY_RELATIONSHIPS_DN PR ON ( PT.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID = PR.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID )
    JOIN PAY_ALL_PAYROLLS_F PY ON ( PAPD.PAYROLL_ID = PY.PAYROLL_ID )
    JOIN PER_ALL_PEOPLE_F PAPF ON ( PR.PERSON_ID = PAPF.PERSON_ID )
    JOIN PAY_CONSOLIDATION_SETS PCS ON ( PCS.CONSOLIDATION_SET_ID = PY.CONSOLIDATION_SET_ID )
    JOIN PER_PERSON_NAMES_F NAME ON ( PAPF.PERSON_ID = NAME.PERSON_ID )
    JOIN PAY_REL_GROUPS_DN PAYREL ON ( PAYREL.PARENT_REL_GROUP_ID = PAPD.PAYROLL_TERM_ID )
    JOIN PER_ALL_ASSIGNMENTS_M PAAM ON ( PAYREL.ASSIGNMENT_ID = PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_ID )
    JOIN PAY_PAYROLL_REL_ACTIONS PPRA ON ( PPRA.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID = PR.PAYROLL_RELATIONSHIP_ID )
    JOIN PER_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPES_VL PASV ON ( PASV.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID = PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_STATUS_TYPE_ID )
    JOIN PER_LEGISLATIVE_DATA_GROUPS_VL LDG ON ( LDG.LEGISLATION_CODE = PAAM.LEGISLATION_CODE )
    LEFT JOIN PAY_PAYROLL_ACTIONS PPA ON ( PPA.PAYROLL_ID = PY.PAYROLL_ID
                                           AND PPA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID = PPRA.PAYROLL_ACTION_ID 
                                           -- TEJASH : SUGGESTION-1 : ADDED FOLLOWING CONDITIONS IN JOIN CONDITIONS INSTEAD OF WHERE CLAUSE
                                         --  AND PPA.ACTION_TYPE IS NULL
                                           -- CHANGED FOLLOWING CONDITION TO USE DATES RATHER THAN CHAR
                                           AND NVL(PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE, DATE '2019-09-01') BETWEEN DATE '2019-09-01' AND DATE '2019-12-01'
                                           AND PPA.CONSOLIDATION_SET_ID = PCS.CONSOLIDATION_SET_ID
                                           AND NVL(PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE,trunc(sysdate)) BETWEEN PAYREL.START_DATE AND PAYREL.END_DATE
                                           AND NVL(PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE,trunc(sysdate)) BETWEEN PAPD.START_DATE AND PAPD.END_DATE 
                                           )
    -- TEJASH : SUGGESTION-2 : USE LEFT JOIN HERE
    LEFT JOIN PAY_TIME_PERIODS PTP ON ( PPA.EARN_TIME_PERIOD_ID = PTP.TIME_PERIOD_ID
    AND PTP.PAYROLL_ID = PY.PAYROLL_ID  )
WHERE
    1 = 1

    AND PAAM.ASSIGNMENT_TYPE = 'E' 
       --ADDED condition---    
    AND PASV.USER_STATUS LIKE '%Payroll Eligible'
    AND ( FINC > PTP.START_DATE
          OR FINC IS NULL )
-- COMMENTED BY TEJASH
--    AND ( PPA.ACTION_TYPE IS NULL 
--              OR ppa.action_type IN ( 'Q', 'R' )
--     ) 
       --  AND ldg.name = Nvl(:P_LEGISLATIVE_GROUP, ldg.name)  
       --AND pasv.user_status = Nvl(:P_ASSIGNMENT_STATUS,  
       --                     pasv.user_status)  
    -- COMMENTED BY TEJASH
    --AND TO_CHAR(NVL(PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE, '2019-09-01'), 'YYYY-MM-DD') BETWEEN ( '2019-09-01' ) AND ( '2019-12-01' ) 
       -------    
    --AND PPA.CONSOLIDATION_SET_ID = PCS.CONSOLIDATION_SET_ID
    AND PAYREL.GROUP_TYPE = 'A'
    AND NAME.NAME_TYPE = 'GLOBAL'
    --AND NVL(PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE)) BETWEEN PAYREL.START_DATE AND PAYREL.END_DATE
    --AND NVL(PPA.EFFECTIVE_DATE, TRUNC(SYSDATE)) BETWEEN PAPD.START_DATE AND PAPD.END_DATE
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAPF.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAPF.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PY.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PY.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN PAAM.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND PAAM.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    AND TRUNC(SYSDATE) BETWEEN NAME.EFFECTIVE_START_DATE AND NAME.EFFECTIVE_END_DATE
    )
    where (ACTION_TYPE_code is null
    or ACTION_TYPE_code in ('Q','R'))
```

Comment: @APC Marked the correct answer in my previous question

Comment: There is a lot to go through in that query, but why do you expect it to roll up - you are asking or rows where action_type is 'Q', 'R' or null. Do you want some grouping? Or only see the nulls if there is no row with 'Q','R'. You have to add a not exists clause for that.

Comment: @TomC, Yes I want the query to be fetched according to action_type... either the action_type is 'Q' OR 'R' or because of the left join.. the action_type is null should be picked. but for all employees this is not working... and the employees with 'Q' and 'R' are also coming in null.. which should not happen

Comment: I think you need to reduce this query down to as few lines as possible that demonstrate your issue. Get rid of all the additional columns, joins, and where clauses, and then show just the columns that are going INTO the join clause, and the result of the join. Add a clause for the specific employeeid that demonstrates the problem, and you should have a much simpler query to debug. I suspect that there are multiple rows for the employee, some that meet the left join conditions, and some that dont, which is why you are getting some nulls.